# Inner product of differential forms. Hodge or metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory

In a Riemannian manifold, its inner product:

$\left( \cdot,\cdot \right)_g : T_pM \times T_pM \to K$

Can be defined as by pairing $\alpha^i$ with $\beta^j$ dual by means of the metric tensor:

$\left( \alpha,\beta \right)_g= \left< \alpha^i, g_{ij}\beta^j \right>$

But also via Hodge-star operator:

$\left( \alpha,\beta \right)_g= \alpha^i \wedge \star\beta^j$

From my (may be wrong) understanding, these definitions look very different to me. One arise only from metric concepts, while the second is about "completing" the space.

**Question:** Is it just that we equip our same $T_pM$ with two different inner products or are they just equivalent definitions? If they are, how are they related then?

Thank you

Comment: The Hodge star is usually defined as the operator making these two inner product coincide. I wonder, what definition are you using?

Comment: Well, I am actually trying to integrate these and set a discrete framework, so maybe there is where my error is.
I understand that if I integrate the Hodge approach, I get something that looks like $\int \alpha^i  \beta^j  dx_i \wedge dx_j \wedge dx_k$., i.e., a volume integral. I don't see how this plays along with the first one, and maybe there is my problem... Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you need a volume element to get from your second definition back from an $n$-vector to a scalar. The star operator uses the inner product, of course, but you still need more there.

Comment: Something is not making much sense in these definitions, could you clarify what you mean by $\alpha^i$ and $\beta^j$?

Comment: I see that I mixed vector and its components. I meant that, in an N-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $\int \alpha \wedge \star \beta = \int \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha^i \beta^i dx_0 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_N = \int \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha^i \beta^i dV $, where $\alpha, \beta \in TpM$ and $\alpha = \alpha^i dx_i$, so $\alpha^i$ are the coefficients of $\alpha$.
If I understood @TedShifrin comment, the first definition is lacking this $dV$ element in order to have the same structure as the second one. Right?